# How to convert Maven profiles to gradle

Tags: gradle

I am in the process of converting test project from maven to gradle. The last part is to convert many maven profiles like this to gradle.

```
   <profile>
        <id>fasttrack_ui_saucelabs</id>
        <properties>
            <selenium.remote>true</selenium.remote>
            <selenium.saucelabs>true</selenium.saucelabs>
            <selenium.browser>chrome</selenium.browser>
            <selenium.platform>Windows 10</selenium.platform>
            <parallel.threads>4</parallel.threads>
            <junit.tag>fasttrack</junit.tag>
            <test.retry>2</test.retry>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>fasttrack_login_hub</id>
        <properties>
            <selenium.remote>true</selenium.remote>
            <selenium.saucelabs>false</selenium.saucelabs>
            <selenium.browser>firefox</selenium.browser>
            <parallel.threads>10</parallel.threads>
            <selenium.host>selenium-test.rec.com</selenium.host>
            <selenium.port>4444</selenium.port>
            <junit.tag>fasttrack-login</junit.tag>
            <test.retry>2</test.retry>
        </properties>
    </profile>
```

How can I convert these profiles/properties to gradle ?

Comment: there is a dedicated chapter in Gradle documentation for migration from Maven to Gradle, related to Maven profiles : see here https://guides.gradle.org/migrating-from-maven/#maven_profiles_and_properties

Answer (score 0):

You could create a plugin for each profile

```
Plugin<Project> fasttrack_ui_saucelabs = (Project project) -> { ... }
Plugin<Project> fasttrack_login_hub = (Project project) -> { ... }

if (condition1) apply plugin: fasttrack_ui_saucelabs
if (condition2) apply plugin: fasttrack_login_hub
```